# Finding $\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X))$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables. The pdf of $Y$ is $f_Y(y)$ with $y \geq a$, while the pdf of $X$ is
>   \begin{equation}
> f_X(x) =  
> \begin{cases} 
> f_{X,1}(x), \quad b \leq x\leq c \\
> f_{X,2}(x), \quad  c < x \leq d 
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation} 
>   where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are all positive real numbers such that $a\leq b<c<d<\infty$. Find $\mathbb{P}[Y<g(X)]$ with $g(X)=(c_1 X^{-c_2})^{-1/c_3}$ where $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$ are positive real numbers.

Here is my latest attempt: 
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X)) =\int_a^\infty(1-F_{g(X)}(y)) f_Y(y) \, dy
$$
Letting $Z=g(X)$.
\begin{align*}
F_Z(z)&=\mathbb{P}(Z<z) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(g(X)<z)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X<g^{-1}(z)) \\
& = F_X(g^{-1}(z)) \\
&=
\begin{cases}
\int_b^{g^{-1}(z)} f_{X,1}(x) \,dx, \quad g(b) \leq z\leq g(c) \\
\int_b^c f_{X,1}(x) \,dx+\int_c^{g^{-1}(z)} f_{X,2}(x) \,dx, \quad  g(c) <z \leq g(d)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
 Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X))= {} &\int_a^\infty (1-F_{g(X)}(y)) f_Y(y) \, dy
= {}  \int_a^\infty(1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)) f_Y(y) \,dy
\end{align*}

Now $g(.)$ is a monotonically increasing function. Hence, $g(b)<g(c)<g(d)$ and the solution depends on the value of $a$ relative to $g(b)$, $g(c)$ and $g(d)$. If $a>g(d)$, the required probability is zero. Otherwise, we have three cases:

(1) If $a<g(b)$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X)) = {} & \int_a^{g(b)}(1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)) f_Y(y) \,dy \\
+ {} &\int_{g(b)}^{g(c)}(1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)) f_Y(y) \,dy \\
+ {} &\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}(1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)) f_Y(y) \,dy
\end{align*}

(2) If $g(b)<a<g(c)$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X)) = {} \int_{a}^{g(c)}(1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)) f_Y(y) \,dy 
+ \int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}(1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)) f_Y(y) \,dy
\end{align*}

(3) If $g(c)<a<g(d)$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X)) = {}  \int_{a}^{g(d)}(1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)) f_Y(y) \,dy
\end{align*}

I am unsure how to proceed from here (or even if my attempt is correct to begin with). Any help with that?

Comment: You need to be more careful about the assumptions you're making as you go through every step. $g$ cannot be a "generic function." For starters, think about the following: what assumptions are you making when you go from $\mathbb{P}(g(X) < z)$ to $\mathbb{P}(X < g^{-1}(z))$? Hint: $g$ cannot be a "generic function" for this step to be valid.

Comment: @Clarinetist In my case, the function is in the form $g(X)=(c_1 X^{-c_2})^{-1/c_3}$ where $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$ are positive real numbers.

Comment: Thus, $g(x)=ux^v$, for some positive $u$ and $v$? Anyway, without further information about the two PDFs involved, one can at most write down a general formula for $P(Y<g(X))$, not really compute it.

Comment: @Did Yes that's true, and yes that's exactly what I would like to do: write down the general formula.

Comment: Hence, **not a real question**, as they say?

Comment: @Did I do not get what do you mean by **not a real question**. I have got the pdfs and cdfs but they're quite complicated and I have tried to simplify my question for readability. I just need some hints to get me started and then I'll apply them to the specific problem I'm tackling.

Comment: General formula: $$P(Y<uX^v)=E(F_Y(uX^v))=\int_\mathbb RF_Y(ux^v)f_X(x)dx$$ Equivalent general formula: $$P(Y<uX^v)=1-P(X<u^{-1/v}Y^{1/v})$$ hence $$1-P(Y<uX^v)=E(F_X(u^{-1/v}Y^{1/v}))=\int_\mathbb RF_X(u^{-1/v}y^{1/v})f_Y(y)dy$$ What now?

Comment: @Did Isn't that what I have done? But I conditioned on $Y$ instead. It seems that in order to find $\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X))$ I need to find $\mathbb{P}(X<g^{-1}(y))$, and that's what I'm having a difficulty with. I don't quite know what to substitute in place of $F_{X}(g^{-1}(y))$ in each of the integrals. What's confusing me is that the pdf of $X$ is a piece-wise function.

Comment: Your terminology is not quite correct in this resect: The supports of both random variables are infinite, in that each contains infinitely many points, but one support is _bounded_ and the other us _unbounded_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this just in case someone else is tackling a problem similar to mine. I've come up with this solution after several trials and have verified it through numerical evaluation. I may be missing something though, given that I am a neophyte to probability.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X))= {} &\int_a^\infty (1-F_{g(X)}(y)) f_Y(y) \, dy
= {}  \int_a^\infty(1-F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)) f_Y(y) \,dy
\end{align*}

with
\begin{align*}
F_X(g^{-1}(z))
=
\begin{cases}
\int_b^{g^{-1}(z)} f_{X,1}(x) \,dx, \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \, \, \, \, g(b) \leq z\leq g(c) \\
\int_b^c f_{X,1}(x) \,dx+\int_c^{g^{-1}(z)} f_{X,2}(x) \,dx, \quad  g(c) <z \leq g(d)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Since $g(.)$ is a monotonically increasing function, $g(b)<g(c)<g(d)$ and the solution depends on the value of $a$ relative to $g(b)$, $g(c)$ and $g(d)$. If $a>g(d)$, the desired probability is zero. Otherwise, we have three cases:

(1) If $a<g(b)$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X)) = {} & \int_a^{g(b)}f_Y(y) \,dy \\
+ {} &\int_{g(b)}^{g(c)}\left(1-\int_b^{g^{-1}(y)} f_{X,1}(x) \,dx\right) f_Y(y) \,dy \\
+ {} &\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}\left(1- \left[ \int_b^c f_{X,1}(x) \,dx+\int_c^{g^{-1}(z)} f_{X,2}(x) \,dx\right]\right) f_Y(y) \,dy
\end{align*}

(2) If $g(b)<a<g(c)$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X)) = {} &\int_{a}^{g(c)}\left(1-\int_b^{g^{-1}(y)} f_{X,1}(x) \,dx\right) f_Y(y) \,dy \\
+ {} &\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}\left(1- \left[ \int_b^c f_{X,1}(x) \,dx+\int_c^{g^{-1}(z)} f_{X,2}(x) \,dx\right]\right) f_Y(y) \,dy
\end{align*}

(3) If $g(c)<a<g(d)$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y<g(X)) = {}  \int_{a}^{g(d)}\left(1- \left[ \int_b^c f_{X,1}(x) \,dx+\int_c^{g^{-1}(z)} f_{X,2}(x) \,dx\right]\right) f_Y(y) \,dy
\end{align*}